# How can i map custom date format in elasticsearch and Kibana4

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, kibana-4

I have nginx logs and i have this date format [02/Mar/2015:13:02:51 +0000]

What should i use in elasticsearch and what i should put in the dateformat field of Kibana4?

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_mapping?pretty'
{
"nginx" : {
"mappings" : {
"t07_nginx" : {
"properties" : {
"@timestamp" : {
"type" : "date",
"format" : "dateOptionalTime"
},
"body_bytes_sent" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"geoip_country_code" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"host" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"http_host" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"http_referer" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"http_user_agent" : {
"type" : "string",
"index" : "not_analyzed"
},
"http_x_forwarded_for" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"message" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"msec request_time" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"remote_addr" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"request_http_protocol" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"request_time" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"request_type" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"request_url" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"status" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"upstream_addr" : {
"type" : "string"
},
"upstream_response_time" : {
"type" : "string"
}
}
}
}
}
```

with the above i can't see any data(events) in Kibana

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does the input plugin for nginx/output plugin for elasticsearch in your fluentd config file look like?

Also, make sure you have your time range setup correctly in kibana. I believe it defaults to 15 minutes.

Comment: my issue with elasticsearch dateformat my dateformat is non standard **02/Mar/2015:13:02:51 +0000**  @Cong Hui

Comment: ` format /^(?<remote_addr>[^ ]*) - (?<geoip_country_code>[^ ]*) - \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\]\s+(?<request_type>[^ ]*) (?<request_url>[^ ]*) (?<request_http_protocol>[^ ]*) "(?<status>[^"]*)" (?<body_bytes_sent>[^ ]*) "(?<http_referer>[^"]*)" "(?<http_host>[^"]*)" (?<host>[^ ]*) "(?<http_user_agent>[^"]*)" "(?<http_x_forwarded_for>[^"]*)" upstream_response_time (?<upstream_response_time>[^ ]*) upstream_addr (?<upstream_addr>[^ ]*) msec (?<msec request_time>[^ ]*) request_time (?<request_time>[^ ]*)/
        time_format %d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z
        read_from_head true`